# Try to plot finance data with datetime but met error TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'd like to  plot finance data with datetime, as below data example shown.
But I get the error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Could you please kindly help me to know why I meet this error, and the solution?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import date2num

plt.figure(2)
datafile = cbook.get_sample_data(self.minuteListFile, asfileobj=False)
print('loading %s' % datafile)

datafile['minute'] =date2num(pd.to_datetime(datafile['minute']).tolist())
plt.plotfile(datafile, (0, 1, 2, 3), checkrows=0, subplots=False)
plt.show()
```

data example -

```
minute,spreadprice,bollup,bollmid,bolldown,buy,short,sell,cover
2014/01/02/09/00,144.0,0,0,1,142,0,0,0
2014/01/02/09/01,143.0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
2014/01/02/09/02,145.0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
2014/01/02/09/03,144.0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
2014/01/02/09/04,142.0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
2014/01/02/09/05,142.0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
2014/01/02/09/06,143.0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
2014/01/02/09/07,143.0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
2014/01/02/09/08,142.0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
2014/01/02/09/09,140.0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
2014/01/02/09/10,140.0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
2014/01/02/09/11,141.0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
2014/01/02/09/12,142.0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
2014/01/02/09/13,142.0,144.0,142.0,141.0,0,0,0,0
2014/01/02/09/14,142.0,144.0,142.0,141.0,0,0,0,0
2014/01/02/09/15,143.0,144.0,142.0,141.0,0,0,0,0
2014/01/02/09/16,142.0,144.0,142.0,141.0,0,0,0,0
2014/01/02/09/17,142.0,144.0,142.0,141.0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: I'd like to recommend [finplot](https://pypi.org/project/finplot/), which is made for finance plotting and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following could be used to plot your data. The main point is that you need to specify the (rather unusual) format of the datetimes (`"%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M"`), such that it can be converted to a datetime object.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("data/minuteData.csv")
df["minute"] = pd.to_datetime(df["minute"], format="%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M")

plt.plot(df["minute"],df["spreadprice"], label="spreadprice" )
plt.plot(df["minute"],df["bollup"], label="bollup" )
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]